# tools,plugins or api's for monitoring java web applications

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have developed a web application in java,i want to monitor the web application.I have used jconsole, but it monitors only java application.I heard about jmon could u tel me how to use jmon or any other tools or plugins are there for monitoring web applications.All your views are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look into http://www.newrelic.com/.